# python script in pipe: errno22

Tags: python, pipe

I want to pass output from one python script into another one as in

```
python -c $'print("world")' | python -c $'import sys \nprint("hello " + sys.stdin.readline())'
```

which works quite well.

Now the first one is to be replaced to have

```
mbed detect | python -c $'import sys \nprint("hello " + sys.stdin.readline())'
```

This yields an error

```
hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ere\...\mbed-os\tools\detect_targets.py", line 90, in main
    print(mcu_toolchain_matrix(platform_filter=mut['mcu']))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

On the other hand, `mbed detect` invoked alone yields reasonable output. 
The mbed tool is installed via `pip install mbed-cli` 
and as i can see installation creates a file `mbed.exe`. 
This means it is an application written in python and compiled into an exe. 
Maybe that latter is the step where piping gets broken??? 
I can see in the stacktrace that problem occurs in the source with `print("")`

```
            print("")
            print("[mbed] Detected %s, port %s, mounted %s, interface "
                  "version %s:" %
                  (mut['mcu'], mut['port'], mut['disk'], interface_version))
            print("[mbed] Supported toolchains for %s" % mut['mcu'])
            #print(mcu_toolchain_matrix(platform_filter=mut['mcu']))
            count += 1
```

Note that i commented out another print. 
If i dont, that problem occurs at that place. 
Very strange..

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: _I want to pass output from one python script into another one as in_ Is there a particular reason you're doing things that way?

Comment: Well yes, the first one is mbed, this is a common tool. ```mbed detect``` yields a description of hardware attached. This string i want to parse, e.g. to find out the port at which it is attached.

Comment: Have you considered just running it inside the script? [Some examples here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)